# C++: Counting function only counts first line

Tags: c++

I have a problem trying to count words inside of a vector. A vector holds every line from a file as an object. v[0] is the first line, v[1] is the second line, so on.

For my countWords() function, it only works for counting v[0]. Any object past that is ignored or missed some how. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int countWords(vector<string> v)
{
    stringstream ss;
    string word;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        ss.str(v[i]);
            while (ss >> word)
                count++;
    }
    return count;
}

void readFile(string filename,vector<string> &v)
{
    fstream file;
    string line;

    file.open(filename,ios::in);
    while(getline(file,line)) { //Reads the file line by line ...
        if(line == "") //... ignoring any empty lines ...
            continue;
        v.push_back(line); //... and puts them into our vector.
    }
    file.close();
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) { //Terminate unless the user enters -ONE- entry.
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>" << endl;
            exit(1);
    }

    string filename = argv[1];
    vector<string> fileContents;

    readFile(filename,fileContents);
    cout << countWords(fileContents) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative to RichieHindle's answer, this works too. Just have the stringstream scope local to the for loop and it will reset properly.

```
int countWords(vector<string> v)
{
    string word;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
      stringstream ss(v[i]);
            while (ss >> word)
                count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Before you reuse stringstream you must do

```
 ss.clear();
```

after your while loop.

You could also declare it inside the `for()` loop, but then it would be reinitialized again. For readabillity, this might be better. Performancewise it could make a difference.

Comment: This is good to know. I was trying to go about it earlier with ss.str(string());, but clear() makes WAY more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I bet `ss` goes into an error state when you've exhausted it for the first time and doesn't reset just because you call `str`.

Declare `ss` inside the for loop and pass the string directly to the constructor. This avoids such problems.

In general, you have the bad habit of declaring your variables in a bunch instead of closest to where you need them, and not using constructors. For example, you could pass the filename to `fstream`'s constructor instead of calling `open`. And you could use `ifstream` so you don't need the second argument.